# Dynamicweb redirect links

Tags: redirect, content-management-system

I need to export a list of all redirect links for a web site which uses Dynamicweb CMS.

There are redirect rules in Management Center > Web and HTTP > Direct paths:
[image]

But this list of redirects is not full, as the web site uses much more rules to redirect from one path to another.

What are the other places that I should check to get all redirect paths?

Answer (score 0):

There is also [Page] table with page short cut links in [PageShortCut] field.